# Как в цикле вывести разные классы ?(wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, циклы, cms

Суть в следующем, верстальщик сверстал иконки шагов. Мне нужно выводить это циклом [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вывести разные классы в цикле [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я начинающий в cms, поэтому не хватает знаний

Comment: `$i = 1;` перед `foreach`.  Цифры 1, 2, 3 замени на `<?=$i++?>`

Comment: Спасибо! суть понял, помогло

Answer (score 2):

Такое уже давно не делают средствами PHP или HTML. По сути, это презентационная вещь, а не контент, а поэтому такое можно сделать стилями:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Только вопрос, как мне сделать с помощью счетчика разные стили ?

Comment: Счетчики для вывода цифр. Для применения стилей к элементам в зависимости от их порядка есть селекторы вида :first-child(), :last-child(), :nth-child() и другие.